# vgaswitcheroo + ATI radeon driver

Tags: drivers, ati, hybrid-graphics, vgaswitcheroo

I want both vgaswitcheroo and ati driver on same machine.
vgaswitcheroo is good at powersaving while I also want 
powerful processing too. Most of the time I switch between 
powersave and performance modes. So can I have different
driver for different modes or atleast have a same kernel
boot into different graphic driver at boot time?